# How do I use Dependency Injection between a Core project and a WPF application with changing pages?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am building a `WPF` program using the `MVVM` Framework, along with `Ninject` for `Dependancy Injection`. I have created two projects, a `.Net Class Library` Core project for use with other `.Net` Applications and a `WPF` specific application.

Currently I am changing pages with my application using an `ApplicationViewModel` with a `Property` `CurrentPage`. `CurrentPage` is an `Enum` type called `ApplicationPage` containing the different pages within my application. Within the MainWindow of my WPF application is a frame whose `Content` is `bound` to the `CurrentPage Property` and uses a value converter to convert the value to different `CustomPages` I have made using a `switch` statment, like so:

```
if (value is ApplicationPage)
    switch ((ApplicationPage)value)
    {
        case ApplicationPage.PageOne:
            return new PageOne();
        case ApplicationPage.PageTwo:
            return new PageTwo();
        default:
            throw Exception;
    }
}
```

I would like to use `Constructor` `Injection` to pass the `View Models` for these pages into a `Page's` `Constructor` within the `Converter`, Using `ViewModels` that have in turn been `Injected` into the `ApplicationViewModel` class, kind of like so:

```
case ApplicationPage.PageOne:
    return new PageOne(PageOneViewModel);
```

My first thought was, is there some way of making the `CurrentPage` `Property` actually a specific `ViewModel` and perform a `switch` on which `ViewModel` so the `Converter` converts a `ViewModel` to a `Page`?

However the **Type** of `CurrentPage` is an issue as it has to be set to one of the `ViewModels` and therefore cannot take the value of a different `ViewModel`, leaving you stuck with only one `ViewModel` `Class` to work with.

My thoughts are: Is there a way to pass in the `ViewModel` to the `Converter`? Or Could I set `CurrentPage` to an `IViewModelFactory` and Create the `ViewModel` within the converter from the Factory? In which case how would I change the value of `CurrentPage` in order to change the page in the application?

Is there a way to stick to `Dependency` `Injection` while following this logic, or is there another way and do I need to rethink my code for page changing? Unfortunately most examples I have seen have fallen into the so called `ServiceLocator` anti-pattern.

Comment: No, no, no. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Comment: There's a debate here honestly but I'll give you my two cents. DI and navigation should not be one of the same when it comes to databinding and ViewModels.  Of course products like Prism allow this and work with it but I dont agree with the approach there.  You can definitely inject views but I would personally recommend not allowing the ViewModel to be injected or control navigation in such a way.  In MVC you allow the controller to dictate the view and navigation but in MVVM you should react to navigation.  In other words, wrote your view models to be more like binding endpoints and ...

Comment: ...navigate reactively.  Build the navigation in the Views layer.  This separates concerns and allows for easier expansion / options / changes to be made to the system on any tier.  I like your navigation view model approach and you can have a unique MVVM style navigation in the views layer but logically it doesn't need and IMO shouldn't be dependent on the ViewModel layer.  This is a long discussion and it is debated online so I won't say it's the way it has to be but I've done alot of work here in various methods and can tell you from my personal experience I wouldn't choose to do it again.

Comment: Separating this logic will also solve your issue I believe.  If you have a unique View system consider it as attachable to your ViewModels.  Don't pretend you know the View from the ViewModel layer and don't pretend the View(s) will always be the same. Build it with the idea any view(s) can attach and work no matter how they are using the VM's.

Comment: Thank you both that was very helpful. Using Data Templates seems to be the way forward. I have found the solution combining both your answers and it works perfectly! My reason for having a seperate navigation ViewModel was simply to allow me to use it again in other projects than this one, but I guess each will have their own navigation needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use data templates as follows,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="View1Template" DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <!-- Custom control style with a Data Context set to a Viewmodel 
        object in the MainWindowViewModel -->
        <local:CustomPage1 DataContext="{Binding CustomPage1ViewModel}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="View2Template" DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <!-- Custom control style with a Data Context set to a Viewmodel 
        object in the MainWindowViewModel -->
        <local:CustomPage2 DataContext="{Binding CustomPage2ViewModel}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then setting a `Data Trigger` within the `Content Control Style`;

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">

            <!-- The Default/initial View being shown -->
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource View1Template}" />

            <!-- Triggers bound to the CurrentView Property -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource View1Template}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource View2Template}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

The `CurrentView` is a property that can be changed in code to `Trigger` a change in the `UI` - can be set to an `Enum` of `PageNames`.